Writing to a RWTexture2D in Fragment shaders
I'm new to this topic, and I know this sounds stupid, but I just really want to learn!
So I found out I can write to RWTexture2D from my fragment shader(according to forum), but I can't really find out how.
I announced an RWTexture2D in my .hlsl file, and have written to it:
RWTexture2D<float> _VisibilityBuffer : register(u1);

float4 Fragment(Interpolators input) : SV_Target
{
    _VisibilityBuffer[input.texelCoords] = input.visibility;
    return _Color * _VisibilityBuffer.Load(int3(input.texelCoords, 0));
}

but then the object renders as a giant pitch-black silhouette.
What could I be doing wrong?

I tried to write visibility data for self-occlusion culling. The datas input.visibility and texelCoords are checked and fine. But instead of the data I tried to write, it somehow returns 0.
texelCoords' ranges between (0, 0) and (242, 3795).
input.visibility ranges between 1 and 0.
[Edit]: I'm doing this to debug my process. the texture is loaded in the hull shader in the next cycle, and the .hlsl file is included in a shaderlab file.
